# Google Drive Api desplegar fotos en una app

Tags: android, api, app

Se puede descargar imágenes de una carpeta de Google Drive para poder desplegarlas en un activity para mi app? Se esta creando un app de ventas donde el catalogo que se mostrara seran fotos que se encuentran almacenadas en una carpeta de Drive y por lo cual se requiere que todas las fotos se muestren, sin necesidad de entrar a google drive.

Comment: El google drive API me abre completamente el drive del usuario y solo quiero que abra unicamente una carpeta a traves del link para compartir

Comment: Si no quieres acceder a la cuenta, manualmente puedes obtener el link de tus fotos y ese adjuntarlo en el source de tus imagenes de tu Activity.

Comment: Lo malo de hacerlo manualmente, es que se seguirá subiendo imágenes constantemente y se quiere hacer dinámico, ese es mi problema, no se si se pueda acceder al link de la carpeta y jalar todas las imágenes que se encuentre ahí

Answer (score 0):

1. Compartir tu foto para que cualquiera pueda ver(Acceso general PUBLICO-LECTOR)
2. Encontrar tu FILE_ID de la foto
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vmo0PnMSPJjnCmHI_A1aaR2KE2lMAC0D/view?usp=sharing   (ej. FILE_ID = 1Vmo0PnMSPJjnCmHI_A1aaR2KE2lMAC0D)
3. Insertar la siguiente url en tu web https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=FILE_ID

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1Vmo0PnMSPJjnCmHI_A1aaR2KE2lMAC0D">
```

4. Tomar un cafecito.